# Can anyone help me with this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, excel

```
Update [sheet1$]
SET [Status] = 'Greater than 100M' 
WHERE [Available Balance in USD] > 100000000 
  AND [Main Category] = 'Free Cash' AND [Sub Category] <> 'abc'
```

Getting an error saying

> datatype mismatch error

The data type of column `[Available Balance in USD]` is `Text`. I need to convert to `Int` and check.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You've tagged three _different_ databases - `MySql`, `SQL Server` and `MS Access`, and then posted a query that mentions `[sheet1$]` which suggests something like Excel... Which database / piece of software are you actually using?

Comment: Yes, I am actually quering to excel.

Comment: There is some Cast function in SQL... the query will look something like this, Update [sheet1$]
SET [Status] = 'Greater than 100M' 
WHERE Cast([Available Balance in USD],INT) > 100000000 
  AND [Main Category] = 'Free Cash' AND [Sub Category] <> 'abc' ..... But getting an error "undefined function Cast"

Comment: @AbhijithRaj Edit your question and fix tags

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you would use `try_convert()`:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, [Available Balance in USD]) > 100000000
```

Comment: Tried this function but getting an error "undefined function"

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Hey guys .. thanks for the suggestions.. Sorted out the issue.. 
used INT([Available balance in USD]) and that will work :)